# Azure Mobile Service receiving a 403 HTTP exception from FourSquare

Tags: azure-mobile-services, foursquare

I have a very strange problem I am hoping that someone can send me in the right direction. I will try give as much information as I can but if I miss anything important I will be more than happy to provide the additional info.

I am trying to make a request to the FourSquare API from an Azure Mobile Services .Net backend but am getting "The remote server returned an error: (403)" doesn't matter what I do! The URL that I am using to test with is below. I am using a very basic request URL for testing to minimise any issues with query string parameters. I have also created a temporary FourSqaure app so that I could provide the exact URL for this post.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=RGRB1T4E2XZN5FMT51VRTSB5VC4AH3HHYJJT5KF5HXFMPK5P&client_secret=0XKMB2ZPUVE1W2MICTNG0ETJPETDNDSNQCVB32WTBBHKNRIC&v=20151021

How things work is there is an AngularJS web client that makes a request up to the Azure Mobile Services API. The mobile service then makes a request to the FourSquare API and returns the results to the AngularJS client.
So this is what is happening: 
1.  When making the request from the Mobile service to FourSquare on my dev machine it works fine
2.  When making the request from another REST Client in Google Chrome to the FourSquare API it works fine
3.  When making the request from a .Net console app on my local machine it works fine. I have added the request that is created below, captured using Fiddler. 
4.  When taking the exact same code from the console app (Shown below) and adding it to the Azure Mobile Service it returns the 403 error. The details of the error are logged in the Azure Portal so I know the client is successfully connecting to the mobile service and that the 403 is coming from the WebRequest.

Fiddler Request (Works locally):

```
GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=RGRB1T4E2XZN5FMT51VRTSB5VC4AH3HHYJJT5KF5HXFMPK5P&client_secret=0XKMB2ZPUVE1W2MICTNG0ETJPETDNDSNQCVB32WTBBHKNRIC&v=20151021 HTTP/1.1
Accept: *.*
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: api.foursquare.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Console Application Code (Works locally but not in cloud)

```
Dim request As WebRequest - WebRequest.Create("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories?client_id=RGRB1T4E2XZN5FMT51VRTSB5VC4AH3HHYJJT5KF5HXFMPK5P&client_secret=0XKMB2ZPUVE1W2MICTNG0ETJPETDNDSNQCVB32WTBBHKNRIC&v=20151021")

request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

With Ctype(request,HttpWebRequest)
   .Accept = "*.*"
   .ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
   .Method = "GET"
End With
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
WriteLine(responseFromServer)
reader.Close()
response.Close()
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot further or even what what i am doing wrong would really be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just so that no one else wastes any time on this like I have I have emailed FourSquare and they have responded saying and I quote "Unfortunately due excessive congestion from Azure in the past week, we have been closely controlling the API traffic that comes in from Azure Web. ". So I have asked them to confirm a few thing particularly if requests are actually being blocked, why the error message gives no indication of that and why they have not made it public. All assuming that I understood the message correctly I will update the post once I have confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FourSquare are currently blocking request that are made from Microsoft Azure servers. I contacted their support not expecting much, especially at this time of the year. They were very good and got back to me very quickly. I even got an email on new years day saying they have resolved my problem.

In short, if you need to make requests to FourSquare from Azure send an email and ask them if they can white list your IP address. My only criticism now is they really should put something in the error response telling you what they are doing so you don’t waste hours of your time chasing your tail.